# CMS Pages and static blocks not editable

Tags: cms, ce-1.9.1.0, cms-block

I am not sure, but I guess this problem appeared after installing the latest Magento 1.9.1.0.
When I want to edit a CMS page or a static block in the admin interface, the area that should display the content fields does not disappear. The list on the left appears on the CMS page, but not the right column. At static blocks the complete page does not render content.

Neither the server log nor the Magento logs list any errors. The rendering just appears to stop as soon as the content fields should be loaded. I suspect the closing tags are just created by the Google Chrome browser, otherwise there would be nothing afterwards. Also the footer is not visible.

[image: No content fields],

Edit: In the log file there are some errors after enabling it in the index.php file:
2016-03-15 14:05:22 Error   MYIP    500 GET /index.php/admin/cms_page/edit/page_id/12/key/e152a21cf52d77869a262babf00d1772/ HTTP/1.1    https://DOMAIN/index.php/admin/cms_page/index/key/3637ecbed73f7eafed680263120a95c0/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36   60.1 K  Apache-SSL-Zugriff

2016-03-15 14:05:22 Warning MYIP        mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem' not found in /PATHTOPAGEROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Config.php on line 85, referer: https://DOMAIN/index.php/admin/cms_page/index/key/3637ecbed73f7eafed680263120a95c0/               Apache-Fehler

2016-03-15 14:05:25 Error   62.138.0.25 404 GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1        Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; seoscanners.net/1; +spider@seoscanners.net)    21.3 K  Apache-SSL-Zugriff

Edit2: Thinking about it I have done a malware scan recently and I know that said malware scan adds a .suspected extension to files which could lead to an error, as the file cannot be found. But I am not sure which file to look for.

Comment: In index.php comment out `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` check any error there?

Comment: Indeed, there are some in the Apache Log File:

Comment: Post in question. May be it will helpful to short out error.

Comment: Sorry about that, they are in the question now, had some troubles updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log it can not find

**/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php file**

File is not available

Comment: That was the problem, as I thought above the malware scan added a .suspected extension. Need to find out now, why it did that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Class `Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem` not found

Check to make sure `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php` exist and has the correct permission. If it does not exist download a fresh copy of your current version from magento. You may also want to do a diff of your code base with the fresh copy you download (keep in mind that patches may cause the files to be different).